# Making drivers 'universal'

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

This is currently how I have my chromedriver initialised

`System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C://chromedriver.exe");`

however just now I've put all my code in a repo and of course this way it relies on everyone having the driver in the same place etc. etc.

Is there any way I can make this work 'universally' across computers without other users having to get the chromedriver and add variables etc.

(apologies if this was answered but I'm not sure how to google it)

Comment: The location of your driver executable is intentionally taken from a system property in order to solve this exact problem. Each computer running your application probably has the executable in a different location, that's why the location is supposed to be passed using the ``-D`` vm argument (which achieves the same as ``System.setProperty``, just independent from the source code).

Comment: Try keeping it in `System -> Path` environment variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your whole project in maven then there is the folder like "resources", if not create a folder with name "resources" and place the chrome driver("chromedriver.exe" which you will use in your project) in that folder.

Then use below piece of code which can be used by any user and no need to download the chrome driver every time.

```
chromepath = System.getProperty("user.dir")
                + "\\src\\main\\resources\\chromedriver.exe";
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", chromepath);
```

**"\src\main\resources\chromedriver.exe"** should be path to your driver at project level.

Please let me know if there are any issues.

Thanks,

Krishna

Comment: Yep, thats worked! Thanks a lot for the assistance working as expected :)